# Pyspark - normalize a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this API response:

```json
{
  '02/09/2021': {
    'ABC': {
      'emp': 'A1',
      'value': '12421'
    },
    'DEF': {
      'emp': 'D1',
      'value': '3345'
    },
    'GHI': {
      'emp': 'G2',
      'value': '260048836600'
    },
    'JKL': {
      'emp': 'J1',
      'value': '66654654'
    }
  }
}
```

and would like to normalize a table in this format:

```
CODE | EMP | VALUE        | DATE
========================================
ABC  | A1  | 12421        | 02/09/2021
DEF  | D1  | 3445         | 02/09/2021
GHI  | G2  | 260048836600 | 02/09/2021
JKL  | J1  | 66654654     | 02/09/2021
```

I tried to make an explode but I couldn't do it, how can I get this result?

---

To reproduce it:

```py
import json

api_response = {'02/09/2021':{'ABC':{'emp':'A1','value':'12421'},'DEF':{'emp':'D1','value':'3345'},'GHI':{'emp':'G2','value':'260048836600'},'JKL':{'emp':'J1','value':'66654654'}}}

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([json.dumps(api_response)])
input_df = spark.read.json(rdd)
```

Comment: How are you reading it? Your JSON seems to be invalid

Comment: I use pyspark, this is a example…

Comment: yeah but I don't know how to read it. Update your question doing these two steps, first collecting some data from your dataframe running `[dataframe].limit(3).collect()` and get the schema `[dataframe].schema.simpleString()` where [dataframe] is your variable name. It will be easier to reproduce it

Comment: @Kafels done, tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to parse your api response into dataframe is first transforming the result, removing the key date and putting it into the body. To transforming it into a table it's required to use `stack`:

```
import json

def transform_api_content(api_response):
  for key, value in api_response.items():
    value['DATE'] = key
    yield json.dumps(value)


api_response = {'02/09/2021':{'ABC':{'emp':'A1','value':'12421'},'DEF':{'emp':'D1','value':'3345'},'GHI':{'emp':'G2','value':'260048836600'},'JKL':{'emp':'J1','value':'66654654'}}}
input_df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(transform_api_content(api_response)))

# Hard-coded
stack = 'stack(4, "ABC", ABC.emp, ABC.value, "DEF", DEF.emp, DEF.value, "GHI", GHI.emp, GHI.value, "JKL", JKL.emp, JKL.value) AS (CODE, EMP, VALUE)'
output_df = input_df.selectExpr(stack, 'DATE')
output_df.show(truncate=False)

# Dynamic
def stack_columns(dataframe):
  struct_cols = [column for column, schema in dataframe.dtypes if schema.startswith('struct')]
  stack_expr = ['"{0}", {0}.emp, {0}.value'.format(column) for column in struct_cols]
  return 'stack({length}, {stack}) AS (CODE, EMP, VALUE)'.format(length=len(struct_cols), stack=','.join(stack_expr))


output_df = input_df.selectExpr(stack_columns(input_df), 'DATE')
output_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output

```
+----+---+------------+----------+
|CODE|EMP|VALUE       |DATE      |
+----+---+------------+----------+
|ABC |A1 |12421       |02/09/2021|
|DEF |D1 |3345        |02/09/2021|
|GHI |G2 |260048836600|02/09/2021|
|JKL |J1 |66654654    |02/09/2021|
+----+---+------------+----------+
```